# How can I replace observations for multiple variables with the same prefix?

Tags: stata

I am attempting to identify which observations are below 15 seconds for timer variables. First, I generated the variable `speed`, and attempted to replace all observations of the variables that start with timer, that are below 15 with 1.

```
gen speed = 0
replace speed = 1 if timer* <15
```

However, Stata is telling me,

```
timer* invalid name
r(198);
```

What might be going on? I'm not sure how to attach my data from Stata here, any insight into that would be appreciated too.

Comment: An observation in Stata is an entire row, record or case in the dataset. Your usage seems different.

Comment: Ah, I think I mean values of an observation? (Several cells across each row).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Stata tag wiki has massively detailed information on how to post a data example.

What is going on is simply that Stata doesn't support your syntax. Indeed, it is not even clear what it might mean.

```
. clear

. set obs 1
number of observations (_N) was 0, now 1

. gen timer1 = 10

. gen timer2 = 20

. list

     +-----------------+
     | timer1   timer2 |
     |-----------------|
  1. |     10       20 |
     +-----------------+

. gen wanted1 = min(timer1, timer2) < 15

. gen wanted2 = max(timer1, timer2) < 15

. l

     +-------------------------------------+
     | timer1   timer2   wanted1   wanted2 |
     |-------------------------------------|
  1. |     10       20         1         0 |
     +-------------------------------------+

.
```

One guess is that you want an indicator which is 1 if any of the variables `timer*` is less than 15, in which case you need to compute the minimum over those variables in an observation and compare it with 15. Another guess is that you want an indicator which is 1 if all of the variables `timer*` are all less than 15, in which case you need first to compute the maximum in an observation. For the simple example above the functions `min()` and `max()` serve well. For a dataset with many more variables in `timer*`, you will find it more convenient to reach for the `egen` functions `rowmin()` and `rowmax()`.

There are other ways to do it, and other wilder guesses at what you want, but I will stop there.